# GRASS v.rast.stats missing in SEXTANTE toolbox

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sextante

I am new in the QGIS world and also with GRASS. I am really interested in using v.rast.stats as it is doing exactly what I need. My problem is that I am not able to find it inside SEXTANTE in QGIS and I don't now how to make it appear.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this module has been removed from sextante:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6364

I can't find in in Lisboa nor Master.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So throught wich software can I use it?

Comment: The original GRASS which comes with QGIS still has the command under `vector -> Attribute update`.

Comment: Thank you again. Really sorry, I am new in this and I can't find what you said: Attribute update. Even I can't use the options from GRASS.

Comment: If you have installed QGIS on Windows with OSGEOW, you have installed a separate GRASS icon. This is independent from QGIS, and GRASS is not as user-frendly as QGIS. But it still works. Other source is http://grass.osgeo.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific information about the version of QGIS that you are using, it is hard to give you more detailed help. However, I would recommend that you consult the [GRASS and Sextante Wiki](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Sextante#Installation) page as it provides detailed information on installing and accessing Sextante and in turn GRASS GIS tools.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. I am using QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa, Sextante 1.0.9 and Grass 6.4.3